# Django - UTC to Local Time Conversion fails

Tags: python, django, django-models, utc, django-timezone

i want to convert my UTC time to my local time

my settings.py

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

my models.py

```
class UnauthorizedAccess(models.Model):
    UnauthorizedAccessId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='UnauthorizedAccessId')
    Camera = models.ForeignKey(Camera, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='CameraId')
    AccessTime = models.DateTimeField()
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "UnauthorizedAccess"
```

views.py

```
from datetime import date, datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from tzlocal import get_localzone
import pytz

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([])
def push_notification(request):
        cam_id = request.data.get("CameraId").strip()
        camera_ob = Camera.objects.get(CameraId=cam_id)
        unauthorized_entry = UnauthorizedAccess(
            Camera=camera_ob,
            AccessTime=timezone.now(),
            Description=unauthorized_access,
        )
        unauthorized_entry.save()
        return Response({msg:  validation["FDP25"]}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.getLogger("error_logger").exception(repr(ex))
        return Response({msg: validation["FDP23"]}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

while saving i tried  AccessTime=datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)  and  AccessTime=datetime.now()
now i am using  timezone.now()

my data base saved the data [image: Database Data]

and i tried retrieving my data

my views.py
from datetime import date, datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from tzlocal import get_localzone
import pytz

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([])
def notification(request):
    try:
        unauthorizedaccess_details = list()
        tz = get_localzone()
        notification_ob = UnauthorizedAccess.objects.all().order_by('-AccessTime')[:50]
        for ob in notification_ob:
            dev = Device.objects.get(Camera=ob.Camera)

            tz = get_localzone()
            localtz = ob.AccessTime.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(tz)
            date_time = localtz.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

            tz1 = ob.AccessTime.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
            localtz1 = tz1.astimezone(timezone.get_current_timezone())
            date_time1 = localtz1.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

            unauthorizedaccess_info = {
                'id': ob.UnauthorizedAccessId,
                'DeviceName': dev.DeviceName,
                'Date': date_time,
                'Date1': date_time1,
                'Date2': ob.AccessTime,
                'Date3':  ob.AccessTime.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"),
                'Access': ob.Description,
                'Type': '1'
            }
            unauthorizedaccess_details.append(unauthorizedaccess_info)
            return JsonResponse(unauthorizedaccess_details, safe=False,  status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.getLogger("error_logger").exception(repr(ex))
        return Response({msg: validation["FDP23"]}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

i tried these method for getting correct time

while i run this using my localhost as url i got this answer ( i am showing only 1 set data as example)

```
{
        "id": 124,
        "DeviceName": "FDP01",
        "Date": "18/08/2020 06:14:43 PM",
        "Date1": "18/08/2020 12:44:43 PM",
        "Date2": "2020-08-18T12:44:43.127Z",
        "Date3": "18/08/2020 12:44:43 PM",
        "Access": "Unauthorized entry",
        "Type": "1"
    }
```

then the same data getting using my server url is

```
{
        "id": 125,
        "DeviceName": "FDP01",
        "Date": "18/08/2020 12:49:05 PM",
        "Date1": "18/08/2020 12:49:05 PM",
        "Date2": "2020-08-18T12:49:05.675Z",
        "Date3": "18/08/2020 12:49:05 PM",
        "Access": "Unauthorized entry",
        "Type": "1"
    }
```

i want the  answer as  "Date": "18/08/2020 06:14:43 PM" from the server ,  these format (date1 and Date2 are the example of code i tried)

using server url date is not converting to my local time zone

1. how can i get the  correct date ?
2. what are the mistakes i done ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this.

### Django Settings 'TIME_ZONE'

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#time-zone) you can set this setting to any valid time zone you want. Django is responsible for translating timestamps from the database in the time zone you specified here.
Because you set TIME_ZONE to 'UTC', you did not use this handy feature.

### Manually Convert DateTime Objects

You can do conversion from one time zone into another on your own.

```
from django.utils import timezone
local_tz = timezone.get_current_timezone() # Asking django about the current timezone
# Django gets this information from the incoming request
my_datetime_local = my_datetime.astimezone(local_tz) # Use this method to change the timezone of already aware datetime objects
```

I'm not 100% sure, but I think the method `get_localzone()` from pytz retrieves the local timezone of your machine. I think this is not what you wanted.
Its best to use djangos helper `timezone` for all modifications on timezone aware datetime objects.